# Dialog with TinyMCE causes error 12003

Tags: ms-word, tinymce-4, office-js

With the newest update to Word (1611) dialogs with TinyMCE causes error 12003: Invalid URL Syntax.

According to [Use the Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#errors-and-events-in-the-dialog-window) the cause is

> The dialog box was directed to a URL with the HTTP protocol. HTTPS is required.

Simple example is to put below code in a dialog (oddly enough it works in a panel).

**Updated code**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Office.js with TinyMCE</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            "use strict";

            // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
            Office.initialize = function (reason) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
                });
            };
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit1:** This is only a problem on Windows. On Mac it works fine.

**Edit2:** The code for opening the dialog

```js
var url = 'https://' + location.host + '/dialog.html';
console.log('url: ' + url); // url: https://localhost:44341/dialog.html
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 30, width: 20 });
```

Comment: Is your hosting html page served via httpS ?

Comment: Yes it is via https.

Comment: I tried the code above in a dialog and I can get the dialog box to appear, then a text box briefly appears but then an error in a yellow bar appears inside the dialog "Add-in Error: A problem occurred while trying to reach this add-in". Is that what you are seeing too?

Comment: Yes, exactly! If you attach an event handler like [this](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#errors-and-events-in-the-dialog-window) it gives error code 12003. I don't know if it is some request internal to the iframe that may not be https. I tried adding a delay to the call to tinyMCE and then the page shows without error until the call to tinyMCE is invoked, and then the error message you mention is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've identified the issue. Turns out we are blocking the *javascript:* URL protocol which seems to be invoked when using TinyMCE. We are working on a fix.

Comment: That sounds really good! CKEditor has the exact same error so you should probably test that as well. Since this bug has been present for two months I had to develop an editor myself so my add-in could work reasonably in that time. Will you let me know when this problem is solved?

Answer (score 1):

12003 usually indicates you don't have https on your dialog url. This issue is more likely raised when displayDialogAsync is called, you are passing a HTTP url in the first argument.

For your html page with TinyMCE, I am able to copy-paste the entire html and open it in Office dialog. Therefore it is unlikely related to the tinyMCE.

(It will be much helpful you could share your code opening up the dialog.)

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question with the code for opening the dialog. I also added the fact that the error is only present in Word on Windows.

Comment: Have you seen the comments made by Humberto and me on the main post. Did you by any chance test this on a Mac or maybe on version 1610 on Windows?