# Dialog API fires a 12003 event when navigating to any SSL link

Tags: office-js

In my add-in I'm using a standard asp.net OAuth 2 implementation to provide authentication from a separate sub domain.  This was previously working in Office 2016 for windows.  It still works on iPad, Mac, and office online.  I've tested in both the MSI version and the Click to run of windows (msi: 16.0.4456.1003, correction click to run "1701".

I am attempting to get a narrower repro and currently even something as simple as clicking a link doesn't work in the dialog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.microsoft.com">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This will respond with a 12003 error.  Also if i uninstall KB3127982 from the MSI machine then things work as expected.

Anyone else experiencing this?

I've got a repro add in that i've published, would that be helpful?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>1d31e1a3-93e9-41a5-b035-81333ca3665c</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="12003Repro" />
  <Description DefaultValue="12003Repro"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://officejsbugrepro.azurewebsites.net</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://www.microsoft.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://www.google.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
     <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://officejsbugrepro.azurewebsites.net/home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Is the domain you are navigating to listed in the <AppDomains> list?

Comment: Yes. i've included the app domain in the list.  Also wouldn't that have been a 12004 error?

Comment: Just as an addition.  For Office 365 -   On the deferred channel the bug isn't there. This code works just fine.  On the current channel it starts throwing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I determined the issue here.

For my actual app, i use a custom OAuth endpoint that we use for all of our products.  That login page had a link for olark chat.  Apparently olark chat loads something that triggers this 12003 error.

This repro above is still triggers the error state, but i was attempting to load https://www.microsoft.com.  Apparently there is something on that page as well that triggers this error state.  I think there may still be a bug in here that is worth investigating but this work around solved it for me.  I removed Olark chat from the login page and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might be relevant: [Dialog with TinyMCE causes error 12003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164617/dialog-with-tinymce-causes-error-12003/42308506#42308506)

> we are blocking the *javascript:* URL protocol

Maybe something similar is happening in your case.